# how to get single value from array in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I stored some data to an array using this code

```
$this->data['result']    =   $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
```

when I print my result by using `print_r($this->data);`

it shows like this

```
Array ( [base_url] => http://localhost/pelikanartline.com/ [result] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 2 [product_code] => 167007 [product_name] => ARTLINE VIVIX HIGHLIGHTERS 10PK YELLOW [product_discription] => some description [xylene_free] => y [rohs_compliant] => y [product_features] => some text ) ) )
```

now I want to store product_id value to a variable like pro_id. please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $pro_id = [];

 foreach($this->data['result'] as $key => $val){
    $pro_id[] = $val->product_id;
 }

 print_r($pro_id);
```

Comment: awesome man...It's working.love you bro... also I remove $pro_id = []; this part. when i use that its getting an error. other wise it 100% perfect...

Comment: @Udara Suranga. If this works kindly accept the answer.

Comment: yes sure..I'm waiting 4 minutes. become they don't allow me to accept answer with in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If your model returns only one record, you can use this shortcut:

`$pro_id  = $this->data['result'][0]->product_id;`